# Renting a car in europe while living on a working visa in the US and having a European drivers license

Tags: usa, europe, automobiles, insurance

I both have a European and an US drivers license and I'm currently living and working in the US, I still have my European passport. I would like to rent a car during the holidays back in Europe, can I rent a car stating that I'm a resident of EU with my European drivers license or do I need to state that I'm a US resident (and pay higher insurance prices)

Comment: Why do you think that your residency makes any great difference to the rental pricing?

Comment: Is your EU driving licence even valid any longer, now that you do not live in the EU?

Comment: @Gagravarr: yes, it makes a big difference in insurance, as a EU citizen the liability insurance is included in the price (without additional cost)

Comment: @MichaelHampton: yes: EU drivers licenses dont expire as quick as US ones, mine even remains valid indefinitly

Comment: In some states such as California the minimum third party liability insurance that will be offered to non-Californian residents is very low (a few thousand dollars) and is unlikely to shield you from significant claims in the event of an accident. You may wish to investigate obtaining more comprehensive insurance depending on the rules in your state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling multiple car rental places and explaining the situation they told me that you are able to rent a car using your EU drivers license and taking advantage of better pricing options through local branch websites, as long as you give them your US address when you book and present your EU license at the counter

Comment: Why did you not just call them in the first place instead of posting that question here?

Answer (score 3):

If you are living and working in the US then you are not a resident of the EU. Telling the rental company that you are leaves your self open to problems. It may invalidate the contract and any insurance you take out. On the other hand that is no reason not to present your EU driver's license If it is valid.

I also doubt that your residency makes a big difference to the price.

Comment: yes, it makes a big difference in insurance, as a EU citizen the liability insurance is included in the price (without additional cost)

Comment: 1 week rental from avis.com = 150 dollar without any insurance
1 week rental from avis.be = 150 dollar with liability and collision damage weaver included (valued at 140 dollar)

Comment: Do you mean EU citizen? Because EU citizen is different from residency.